# What is going on here? 0.1 * integers gives more decimals than expected

Tags: python, loops, integer, floating-accuracy

Something is happening and I have no idea why.

In python:

```
for j in range(1,10):
      print(0.1*j)
```

which returns:

```
0.1
0.2
0.30000000000000004
0.4
0.5
0.6000000000000001
0.7000000000000001
0.8
0.9
```

what is happening?

Comment: perhaps `0.1*integer` returns a float because `0.1` is a float? What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: My question is wrong ahaha but I mean why do I get 0.000001 ?

Comment: What is bugging you? According to the title of your question, you're expecting `0.1*int` to give you something else than a `float`, which is somewhat normal...

Comment: See the linked-to question (the duplicated one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/4996248). This is just standard floating point behavior since base 2 and base 10 don't really mesh well.

Comment: where is the linked question?

Comment: Consider reading into float data types.  In the meantime if you want 3*.1 to give you 0.3 consider using a floor or round function.